# Discord.js hex colors don't work, and it just turns grey

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am working on a bot that could change role colors, and I pretty much have the entire code ready, but for some reason, when I run the command, the color just turns grey.

```js
var red = ['#ff0000']

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === 'grimm!change Co-Admin red'){
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Server Owner");
            role.edit({
                color: red
            })
    }})
```

And right when I use this, it just changes the color to grey. Does anyone see any issue with this? I have also tried using different color hex and RGB values, but nothing works.

Comment: Why are you putting the value inside of an array?

Answer (score 2):

You better check if the role exists first. Do this:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Server Owner");
if(!role){ return message.reply("No role found"); }
role.edit({
    color: "#FF6F61" //Using hex color
})
```

And since you're doing

```js
let red = ["#ff6f61"];
```

You'll have to do

```js
role.edit({
    color: red[0]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=color), the role color should be a Base 10 Number. You can find a list of colors [here](https://gist.github.com/thomasbnt/b6f455e2c7d743b796917fa3c205f812), and an example [here](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/). In your case, this would be:

```
role.edit({ color: 16711680 })
```

Comment: It does not, actually. It can be a base 10 number, but it can very well be a HEX code, rgb, etc.

Comment: No, the linked docs mention that the `color` property returns the base 10 color of the role, not that it has to be a base 10 number.